# Unable to use OR condition in elastic search query

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Trying to use an OR condition for a given field. Searching for multiple search patterns but each time the query is executed it only returns data for one of the search strings whereas if searched individually fetches the required data.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {"makeIt": {"value": "foo"}}
                },
                {
                    "term": {"makeIt": {"value": "roo"}}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Should return all available values for an sql

```
select * from tablename where makeIt in ("foo","roo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combining two term queries using a `should` clause, you can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "makeIt": [
        "foo",
        "roo"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query given in the question is also correct. I tested it against a sample index data and got the below result (for both the queries)

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "69027360",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "makeIt": "foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "69027360",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "makeIt": "roo"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

As mentioned by @Val in the comments, by default Elasticsearch returns 10 documents if no `size` param is set. This might be possible that you have more than documents containing `foo` or `roo`.
You need to add the `size` param in your query to get search results containing both the terms.

Modify your search query as

```
{
  "size": 20,           // note this
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "makeIt": [
        "foo",
        "roo"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SJJ please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ? If still you are not getting any results, then please share your index mapping

Comment: The issue unfortunately remains the same that it returns data for only one of the search patterns in either of the queries.

Comment: @SJJ can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: Both terms are matched by the query, but the problem is that the first 10 documents that return have the same term, because there's no way to specify that you would like a mix of the two in the response. If you return a large enough size, you'll eventually start seeing both terms in your response

Comment: ```"makeIt": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    },
                    "ignore_above": 20000```

Comment: @Val oh yes, it should definitely be because of `size` param. Thanks for pointing this out ;-) Let me add this in the answer

Comment: @SJJ you need to add `size` param in your search query. Please go through the updated part of the answer

Comment: @Val,@ESCoder: Thanks for your input but it still doesnt return the desired output.Anyway by which we can determine what should be value for the parameter size?

Comment: @SJJ do you have an idea of how many documents have `"makeIt":"foo"` ? Otherwise you can run a term aggregation to get the doc count

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @SJJ wants to return all documents in one shot, right?

Comment: Next question, are there more than 10000 documents?

Comment: type": "illegal_argument_exception",   "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000]